# Mysql table id 10 on second row

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm have create a MySql table. But I have a problem if i'm insert data into table.

My table row is look like this

```
ID       name
RS1      a
RS10     j
RS2      b
RS3      c
RS4      d
RS5      e
RS6      f
RS7      g
RS8      h
RS9      i
```

Why ID no.10 is add on the second row?
I'm using MySQL Workbench to create the table, anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: How are you querying the data?  Remember:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no inherent ordering.  Any ordering you need is provided explicitly using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Remember that isn't a number but a string and as such that's how it is sorting the column. Also as pointed out the table isn't inherently ordered... Workbench is likely doing that sort for you and using Windows String sorting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would speculate that you are querying the table as:

```
select t.*
from t
order by id;
```

This orders by the `id` in *alphabetic* ordering, not numeric ordering.  Because "1" < "2", "10" appears before "2".

Here is one easy way to fix this:

```
select t.*
from t
order by length(id), id;
```

There are other ways, such as:

```
order by substr(id, 3) + 0
```

This converts everything from the third character onward to a number, which is more suitable for sorting.

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome answer

Answer (score 0):

**It is being sorted by Workbench as a string.**

Unless it is necessary to prepend the id with a string value, I would recommend you use an auto increment field if you are concerned with the viewing order. If it was a number (auto increment) this wouldn't be an issue.

Also consider having a `created` or `created_at` `DateTime` field if you want a chronological sort.

My guess is that you're on a Windows OS which is where I've most often encountered this issue of string sorting being off from expectations.